# Convergence of the Picard iteration with an incorrect initial guess

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-calculus

Consider the system of differential equations $\boldsymbol{y'} = f(t,\boldsymbol{y}(t))$ subject to the initial condition $\boldsymbol{y}(t_0) = \boldsymbol{y_0}$. The Picard–Lindelöf theorem guarantees the existence and uniqueness of a solution of this system under the assumption $f \colon \mathbf{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbf{R}^n$ is uniformly Lipschiz in $\boldsymbol{y}$, i.e., $||f(\boldsymbol{y}) - f(\boldsymbol{z})|| \leqslant K||\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{z}||$ for some $K \geqslant 0.$ The proof involves analyzing the convergence properties of a sequence $(\phi_j)_{j \in \mathbf{N}}$ of approximate solutions, called the sequence of successive approximations. This sequence is obtained by translating the system of DEs into a system of integral equations. Integrating both sides of $\boldsymbol{y'} = f(t,\boldsymbol{y}(t))$, we get

$$\boldsymbol{y}(t) = \boldsymbol{y_0} + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,\boldsymbol{y}(s)) \text{d} s.$$

$\boldsymbol{\phi}(t)$ is the (unique) solution of the system of differential equations if and only if it solves the above integral equation. Let $\boldsymbol{\phi_0}(t) = \boldsymbol{y_0}.$ The sequence of successive approximations

$$\boldsymbol{\phi}_j(t) = \boldsymbol{y_0} + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,\boldsymbol{\phi}_{j-1}(s)) \text{d} s $$

can be shown to converge uniformly to $\boldsymbol{\phi}(t)$ under the assumption $f$ is Lipschitz.

For example, in the case of the (scalar-valued) system $y' = y$ subject to $y(0) = 1$, a straightforward computation shows

\begin{align*}
    \phi_0(t) &= 1 \\
    \phi_1(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \text{d} s = 1 + t \\
    \phi_2(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t (1+s) \text{d} s = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} \\
    \vdots \\
    \phi_N(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \bigg( 1+s+\frac{s^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{s^{N-1}}{(N-1)!} \bigg) \text{d} s = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{t^N}{N!} \longrightarrow e^t, \\[-6pt]
\end{align*}

as $N \to \infty$.

In an exercise on a recent homework, I analyzed convergence of the sequence of successive approximations with initial guess $\phi_0(t) = \cos t$? One can show (through a series of serpentine calculations) that $\phi_j \to e^t$ in this case.

That the iteration with an incorrect guess converges (to the correct solution of the system!) surprised me and other students in the class. Since working on this problem, I have begun to wonder: **if $\phi_0$ is an incorrect initial guess, when does the sequence of successive approximations converge to the true solution? What assumptions on $f$ and $\phi_0$ are needed for this to be the case in general?** In the case of the $y' = y$ system with the given IC:

- If $\phi_0(t) = 0$ almost everywhere (in the sense of the Lebesgue measure), $\phi_j(t) \to e^t.$ To see this, note that the method of successive approximations "self-corrects" in the first iteration:

\begin{align*}
    \phi_1(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \phi_0(s) \text{d} s = 1 \\[3pt]
\end{align*}

- If $\phi_0 = a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_n t^n$ is a polynomial, the sequence of successive approximations converges to $e^t.$ This follows from a straightforward calculation:

\begin{align*}
    \phi_1(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \sum_{j=0}^n a_j s^j \text{d} s = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \frac{t^{j+1}}{(j+1)} \\
    \phi_2(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \bigg(1 + \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \frac{s^{j+1}}{(j+1)} \bigg) \text{d} s = 1 + t + \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \frac{t^{j+2}}{(j+2)(j+1)} \\
    \vdots \\
    \phi_N(t) &= 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{t^{N-1}}{(N-1)!} + \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \frac{t^{j+N}}{(j+N)(j+N-1)\cdots(j+2)(j+1)}, \\[-12pt]
\end{align*}

For a fixed $t$, the denominator in the rightmost term is dominant in the limit as $N \to \infty$. An extra factor of $t$ is being added to the numerator, while terms which are becoming larger and larger are being multiplied together in the denominator. Thus,

$$\lim_{N \to \infty}  \phi_N(t) = e^t + \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \underbrace{\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{t^{j+N}}{(j+N)(j+N-1)\cdots(j+2)(j+1)}}_{\text{$=0$}} = e^t.$$

I would bet that a sufficient condition for convergence is that $\phi_0$ is real analytic on the domain of integration, but I am having some trouble in justifying an interchange of limits in the proof.

If $\phi_0 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n t^n$, we have

\begin{align*}
    \phi_1(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n s^n \text{d} s \\
    &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \int_0^t s^n \text{d} s \\
    &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
    \phi_2(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \bigg( 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \bigg) \text{d} s \\
    &= 1 + t + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{t^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
    &\vdots \\
    \phi_{N}(t) &= 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{t^{N-1}}{(N-1)!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} p_{N,n}(t) \\[-12pt]
\end{align*}

where $p_{N,n}(t) = t^{n+N}/(n+N)\cdots(n+1)$ is the degree $n+N$ polynomial obtained in the $N$th iteration. (Note: the uniform convergence of Taylor series is used to interchange integration and summation at every iteration.) As $N \to \infty$, larger and larger factors will be added to the denominator, while a factor of $t$ will be added to the numerator. If we are allowed to interchange the the limit as $N \to \infty$ and the summation, we should get $\lim_{N \to \infty} \phi_N(t) = e^t$.

(Upon re-writing the summation over $n$ as an integral with respect to the counting measure $\mu$, one can use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to interchange limiting operations. If

$$ a_{n} p_{N,n}(t) = a_n \frac{n! t^{n+N}}{(n+N)!} \downarrow 0$$

as $N \to \infty$, the MCT implies

$$\lim_N \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} p_{N,n}(t) = \lim_N \int a_{n} p_{N,n} \text{d} \mu =  \int \lim_N a_{n} p_{N,n} \text{d} \mu = 0.$$

I think the convergence is monotone, but do not know sure to show this for $t > 1$.)

I am interested in (1) verifying if the above limits can be interchanged and (2) if we can use, e.g., the density of polynomials in the space of continuous functions (with the $\sup$ norm) to prove $\phi_j \to e^t$ for all $\phi_0$ which are sufficiently continuous (or integrable). If not, are there necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the Picard iteration to converge with the wrong initial guess?

Comment: All that said I don't actually know how to handle your question at this level of generality, especially when you're interested in things like infinite time horizons. The usual Banach fixed point type theory will already struggle with just the matter of finding a domain that the iteration operator maps into itself, let alone getting contractivity there.

Comment: What, exactly, is a "correct initial guess", what property makes it correct and other choices incorrect? The Banach FPT gives convergence from any point of the space under consideration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann In typical applications the iteration operator is not globally contractive. In particular in the setting of Picard-Lindelof, even if $f$ is globally Lipschitz with constant $L$, the iteration operator is still only Lipschitz with constant $LT$, so you can only get convergence out of the fixed point theorem on a $L^{-1}$ time horizon. Thus in principle the theory would tell you to use the FPT for the problem in the OP on, say, $[0,1-\delta]$ then on $[1-\delta,2-2\delta]$ and so on, not that you would get the whole solution all in one go (which you actually do, at least pointwise).

Comment: That said I do not know why OP believes that $1$ is a better initial guess in this context than $\cos(t)$ is.

Comment: @Ian: I did not say that the Picard iterator is globally contractive, I was referring to the metric space at the end of the construction, where the fixed-point theorem can be applied. Then any continuous function $[x_0-h,x_0+h]\to B(y_0,b)$ with $h=\min(a,b/M)$ can serve as initial point.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see what you meant now, so from the point of view of the FPT the question of "correctness" is whether it's in this ball in $C^0([x_0-h,x_0+h],\mathbb{R})$. But the OP is not going about things using this "hierarchical iteration" (push out the time horizon by $h$ and then re-initialize), so the FPT doesn't really do what the OP is trying to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening in your particular situation with $y'=y$ is simple. If $\phi_0$ is bounded by some $M$ then $\left | \phi_n(t)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{t^k}{k!} \right | \leq M \frac{|t|^n}{n!}$ which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ for any fixed $t$. The proof of this is based on the observation that

$$\phi_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n!} + \int_0^t \int_0^{t_1} \dots \int_0^{t_{n-1}} \phi_0(t_n) dt_n dt_{n-1} \dots dt_1$$

which you can easily prove by induction. Then just apply the triangle inequality after subtracting off the truncated exponential to get the desired result.

If $\phi_0$ is not bounded (but is defined and continuous on the entire line) then you can repeat this argument on any finite subinterval instead.

This is very particular to this case, though. I wouldn't expect this type of estimation to work out in general.

The way the fixed point theorem is actually applied in this situation, you argue that since $f$ is Lipschitz in $y$ with constant $L$, the iteration operator itself is Lipschitz with constant $LT$ where $T$ is the length of the time interval under consideration. Then the fixed point theorem applies as long as $T<L^{-1}$, so you can run the iteration up to there. Then mathematically speaking you can just "restart" the process at a new $t_0$ and propagate from there.

Comment: Thanks, Ian! Can you explain how you got your the estimate for the error in $\phi_n$ and series expansion for the exponential (truncated at $n$)?

Comment: @MeteYuksel See my edit.